# Parsing JSON results into error due to unformatted JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Server side code returns in JSON format where return type is of query.

```
{
    "COLUMNS": ["COUNT", "ISOFLG", "FULLNAME", "WDND", "WHEELBASE", "CLASS", "LIAB", "WT", "SYMBOL"],
    "DATA": [
        [1, "ASD", "F-150", "Y", 144.0, 83, "07", 00000, 21]
    ]
}
```

I am getting an error while parsing it because of the value `00000`. How can we convert result data into string format so that `00000` will be in `"00000"` format to resolve this issue?

Comment: What server side code are you using?  What are you using to parse the json?  You could resolve this by sanitizing the data, either converting `00000` to `0` or `"00000"`

Comment: FYI you can test a string using http://jsonlint.com and it will diagnose any errors. In this particular case you should fix the code which is generating the mal-formed JSON.

Comment: Only thing you could do in JS would be an ugly search and replace solution. You ought to fix it such that you're getting valid JSON data in the first place.

Comment: a simple regex like search would do the trick. should be a for loop and a couple more lines. Not that bad.

Comment: I can change 00000 to 0 or 07 to 7 in server side, that will be a solution for now.
Thanks for your response guys..